# Instances pointing to the same array

Tags: python

here is my problem. I want to create a class which with static array visible for every instance of my class and created only once. The problem is this array does not have constant dimension but instead it will be created with given size by instance of class.

Here is an example

```
class My(object):
   def __init__(self, N):
      self.a = My.arr(N)

   @classmethod
   def arr(cls, N):
      return [i for i in range(0,N)]
```

The problem is every Instance will have a copy of the array. I would like to create let's say two instances

```
p1 = My(5)
p2 = My(5)
```

But the array should be created once and stored somewhere in a memory. When I specify different dimension it should create another array which would be visible for the same dimension instances.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve? Or why do you need it to be a class variable?

Comment: this array with [1,2,3,..] was just an example to point out the problem. In reality I would use sparse matrices from scipy with some entries (not so simple). I have to idea to create two class arrays - one storing size of already created arrays and second one with adress of the memory where the array starts. Is it possible to set pointer to this memory cell like in c++?

Comment: If there is no array - it creates it. If it is present, it sets pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, but I must say it's a very peculiar design pattern:

```
class My(object):
    _arrays = {}

    def __init__(self, N):
        self._dimension = N
        self._arr(N)

    def _arr(self, N):
        if N not in self._arrays:
            arr = [i for i in range(0,N)]
            self._arrays[N] = arr
        return self._arrays

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._arrays[self._dimension]

    @a.setter
    def a(self, new):
        if len(new) != self._dimension:
            raise ValueError('Wrong length, should be %d but was %d' %
                             (self._dimension, len(new)))
        self._arrays[self._dimension] = new


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = My(5)
    b = My(5)
    c = My(10)
    print "# Instances of the same size get the same array:"
    print "a.a and b.a same instance: %r" % (a.a is b.a)
    print "a.a and c.a same instance: %r" % (a.a is c.a)

    a.a[0] = 'five'
    c.a[0] = 'ten'
    print "# Updating the arrays work:"
    print "a array contents: %r" % a.a
    print "b array contents: %r" % b.a
    print "c array contents: %r" % c.a

    a.a = list('abcde')  # new array
    print "# Changing the reference to a new array works:"
    print "a array contents: %r" % a.a
    print "b array contents: %r" % b.a

    print "# Size is protected:"
    a.a = [1, 2, 3]
```

In this class, each time an instance is created, the `_arr` method is called. It will create and store a new array of the correct length in the dictionary `_arrays`, which is a class member. The correct array for the current instance is looked up when the property `a` is accessed or changed.

You could also set `self.a = self._arrays[self._dimension]` but it won't work if you try to assign a new array like `a.a = [1, 2, 3]` and you might also end up with an array of the wrong length. The setter takes care of checking that.

The output looks like this:

```
# Instances of the same size get the same array:
a.a and b.a same instance: True
a.a and c.a same instance: False
# Updating the arrays work:
a array contents: ['five', 1, 2, 3, 4]
b array contents: ['five', 1, 2, 3, 4]
c array contents: ['ten', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# Changing the reference to a new array works:
a array contents: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b array contents: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
# Size is protected:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arrays.py", line 47, in <module>
    a.a = [1, 2, 3]
  File "arrays.py", line 22, in a
    (self._dimension, len(new)))
ValueError: Wrong length, should be 5 but was 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class My(object):
    arraystore = {}
    def __init__(self, n):
        if not n in My.arraystore:
            My.arraystore[n] = range(n)
        self.a = My.arraystore[n]

a5 = My(5)
print a5.a, id(a5.a)

a5.a[3] *= 10

b5 = My(5)
print b5.a, id(b5.a)

c = My(7)
print c.a, id(c.a)
```

**typical output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 3074609804
[0, 1, 2, 30, 4] 3074609804
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 3074604812
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
class My(object):
    a = None  # shared class attribute

    def __init__(self, N):
        My.arr(N)

    @classmethod
    def arr(cls, N):
        if cls.a is None:
            cls.a = list(range(N))
        elif len(cls.a) != N:
            raise ValueError('attempt to change dimension of "a"')

p1 = My(5)
p2 = My(5)
p1.a[0] = 42
print(p1.a)  # --> [42, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(p2.a)  # --> [42, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```